# The Poincare group: rank and casimirs.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is often stated without proof in the particle physics literature that the Poincare group has rank $2$ and that as a result, the corresponding Lie algebra has exactly $2$ casimirs.

How can one show (preferably without the use of two many high-powered sledge hammer theorems) that the Poincare group has rank $2$?

Moreover, if one knows that the rank is $2$, how does it follow that the Poincare algebra has precisely two casimirs?  I know how to construct the two casimirs, but it's not clear to me how the dimension of a Cartan subalgebra restricts the number of casimirs.

Comment: What is Poincare group?

Comment: @studiosus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group

Comment: If you haven't already seen them, Qmechanic has some relevant discussion in his answers (and associated comments) here:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64929/when-are-there-enough-casimirs/64978#64978 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63394/definition-of-casimir-operator-and-its-properties/63398#63398

Comment: and this nice answer by David Bar Moshe:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80949/rank-of-the-poincare-group  I'll stop now...

Answer (score 3):

There are several notions of rank in the literature: Ordinary rank, reductive rank and semisimple rank. The first indeed equals 2 for Poincare group. The other two are equal to 1.

Definition: Rank of a Lie algebra is the dimension of its maximal Cartan subalgebra. A subalgebra is Cartan it it is nilpotent and is self-normalizing.

To see that 2 is a lower bound for the Poncare group consider a light-like line through the origin and its stabilizer in SO(1,3), which consists of elliptic rotations about this line. The subgroup of Poincare group generated by these two is abelian 2-dimensional. One then checks that it is self-normalizing. Checking that 2 is maximal possible dimensions for Cartans is a bit ugly case-by-case analysis. Let me know if you want to see it.

In case of a semisimple Lie group (and Poincare group is not semisimple!) rank equals the dimensional of the space of Casimir elements (Racah theorem). I am not sure what happens in the non-semisimple case you care about, but a generalization of Racah theorem was proven for such groups in Theorem 15.1 in

"Classical Groups for Physicists", by Brian G. Wybourne, 1974.

I looked at his formula but it did not quite make sense to me, maybe you can figure it out (it might be the rank, but in some very odd form).

Comment: Since Josh expressed absolutely no interest in the answer to his question, I will refrain from providing any further details.

Comment: Well I know this is almost a decade late, but I'm interested in further details (e.g. the case-by-case analysis)!  I'm not sure why I never responded before, thanks for your answer.